# Keras Custom Lambda Layer Tensor Manipulation Error

Tags: python, lambda, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a lambda layer that will perform some deterministic masking (I'm not talking about the Keras Masking layer) before pumping out the final output. This is what I have so far:

```
def binary_mask(x):
    # Mask is half the size of x. 
    # 1 if pred1 > pred2 element-wise, 0 otherwise.

    pred1, pred2 = tf.split(x, 2, 1)
    mask = tf.greater(pred1, pred2)
    mask = tf.to_float(mask)
    return mask

def mask_output_shape(input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], units)
```

And this is how I create the layer with the functional API:

```
outputs = Lambda(binary_mask, output_shape=mask_output_shape)(inputs)
```

I'm getting a very weird error coming from my optimizer. It appears that my gradient is `None`.

However, if I replace my current code in `binary_mask` with any of the example `Lambda` layer implementations, it works fine, e.g. `return x`. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm fairly certain that my `mask` is in fact a valid tensorflow tensor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that I don't quite understand the purpose of converting `inputs` into a vector of 0s and 1s, but this operation is clearly not differentiable. That's why no gradient is returned (i.e. gradient is `None`).

Maybe you can try a "softer" version for this function. For example, `sigmoid(a - b)` can be a softer version of `1 if a > b else 0`.

```
outputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.sigmoid(x[0] - x[1]))([pred1, pred2])
```

Comment: I kind of see what you're saying. But my target output is a vector of 0s and 1s. Why would that still be a problem?

Comment: For backpropagation to work, the output at every layer should be differentiable w.r.t. its input. In general, if you have an "idea" that requires a non-differentiable operation at certain layers, you can try to replace it with a "softer version" for gradient computation.